# Volley Multipart Request getBodyContentType not working

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to send `image` and `string` parameters to server with `volley` `SimpleMultiPartRequest` but print response from else part and got message enter userid value but still i am giving the userid in `params`, It not working i try to find more solution but no one is working please suggest me what is going wrong in this and I am new for volley `Multipart` request and i could not found that what is going wrong in it..

**here is my volley request**

```
private void addDetailsMultipartRequest(String userId,String Laddress,String description,String fishTypeId,
                                            String quantity,double lat,double longitude,String date,String ispublic){

        SimpleMultiPartRequest addDetailsMultiPartRequest = new SimpleMultiPartRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                Constants.BASE_URL+getResources().getString(R.string.add_details_url),
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try{

                            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);

                            JSONObject Json=jsonObject.getJSONObject("settings");

                            String mesg=Json.getString("message");
                            if (Json.getString("success").equals(Constants.SUCCESS_CODE)){
                                Toast.makeText(context,"success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }else {
                                Toast.makeText(context,"went wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        }catch (Exception e){
                            //loader.dismiss();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(context,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //loader.dismiss();
            }
        }){

            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
                return headers;
            }


        };
        addDetailsMultiPartRequest.addStringParam("iUserId", userId);
        addDetailsMultiPartRequest.addStringParam("vLocationName", Laddress);
        addDetailsMultiPartRequest.addStringParam("iFishTypeId",fishTypeId);
        addDetailsMultiPartRequest.addStringParam("iQuantity",quantity);
        addDetailsMultiPartRequest.addStringParam("vDescription",description);
        addDetailsMultiPartRequest.addStringParam("vLatitude",""+lat);
        addDetailsMultiPartRequest.addStringParam("vLongitude",""+longitude);
        addDetailsMultiPartRequest.addStringParam("dAddedDate",date);
        addDetailsMultiPartRequest.addStringParam("ePublic",ispublic);
        addDetailsMultiPartRequest.addStringParam("lang_id","EN");
        addDetailsMultiPartRequest.addStringParam("ws_token","WS/create_token/?ws_preview_type=android");

        if (mfile!=null && mfile.exists()){
            addDetailsMultiPartRequest.addFile("vImage", mfile.getPath());
        }else {
            addDetailsMultiPartRequest.addFile("vImage","");
        }

        volleyRequestQ.add(addDetailsMultiPartRequest);
    }
```

Comment: multipart support for volley is really bad , if you are new I would suggest you to use [Android Upload Service](https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service) ,see wiki part for how to use